# Thinkpad X201 Video Driver?

Tags: drivers, video, thinkpad

im fairly newbish when it comes to linux, I've been hunting down video drivers for this Thinkpadx201 tablet because I wanna see if installing them will allow blender to work. Blender sends back a no video driver error when I launch it. It uses an Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD (GMA 4500MHD). Thankyou in advance for the help. Im also running ubuntu 20.04